# Docker container can't resolve names

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rhel, nslookup

I have a strange problem: in RHEL 8.9 docker compose (v2.24.2), (docker - v25.0.1) runs container created by docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  <service>:
    image: <image>
    restart: always
    privileged: true
    environment:
      HTTPS_PROXY: "<HTTPS_PROXY>"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /home/<user>/<folder>/config:/etc/<folder>
```

At first it works as excpeceted, but then it stop resolve names.
resolv.conf file from the container:

```
docker exec -it <container> cat /etc/resolv.conf
search <domains>
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options rotate attempts:2 timeout:2 ndots:0
```

The error:

```
docker exec -it <container> nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Previously it could resolve the name.
Rebooting the docker helps to fix this issue for some time. It also can't ping any server (except the host where it's located).